# Populating An Array In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**JavaScript:**

I am trying to populate an array.

```
var blocks = [];
var blocksCount = 7;


for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < blocksCount; columnIndex++) {
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < blocksCount; rowIndex++) {

    blocks[columnIndex][rowIndex] = 'Some Value';

  }
}
```

The error message says: `undefined is not an object`!

What do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: Where were you running this code? Both Chrome and Node 6.9.1 report `Cannot set property '0' of undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blocks[columnIndex]` is not defined when you are assigning a value to the `rowIndex` on it. You cannot assign a value to something that is not defined yet. Hence, define `columnIndex` as an empty array when it is not defined yet i.e for the first time. You can do like this,

```
blocks[columnIndex] = blocks[columnIndex] || [];
```

```js
var blocks = [];
var blocksCount = 7;


for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < blocksCount; columnIndex++) {
 blocks[columnIndex] = blocks[columnIndex] || [];
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < blocksCount; rowIndex++) {
    
    blocks[columnIndex][rowIndex] = 'Some Value';

  }
}

console.log(blocks);
```

Comment: what is `||` ??

Comment: It is an `OR` operator , it means , if the value on the left hand side to `||` is defined then it will be assigned to `blocks[columnIndex]` OR its value will be   the one on the right side i.e `[]`

Comment: No problem. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign an array to `blocks[columnIndex]` before you try to assign a value to a property of that array.

Comment: could you explain why?

Comment: @Timo — Because you can't assign something to a property of `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you do not have a multidimensional array.

```
var arr = [];
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Will return `undefined` and you are attempting to assign new elements at this point.

You can overcome this and create a multidimensional array within your first `for` loop statement and create a new array within the original `blocks` array.

```
 blocks[columnIndex] = [];
```

You can then assign both values to the multidimensional array.

```js
var blocks = [];
var blocksCount = 7;
        
for (var columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < blocksCount; columnIndex++) {
   blocks[columnIndex] = [];

   for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < blocksCount; rowIndex++) {
     blocks[columnIndex][rowIndex] = 'Some Value';
     console.log(blocks[columnIndex][rowIndex]);
   }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ybsdL4q7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `from` constructor of an `Array` to pass a function into the array creation. This means no need for `for` loops :)

```js
const blockCount = 7;
const block = Array.from({ length: blockCount }, (_, i) => {
  return Array.from({ length: blockCount }, (_, j) => 'Some Value');
});

console.log(block);
```